# browser not support my Jquery Code

Tags: jquery, browser, selector

i have this code for select city & country :

```
$('select[name=province]').change(function(){
    var province_selected = $(this).val();
    $("select[name=city] option").css('display','none');
    $('select[name=city] option[owner*='+province_selected+']').css('display','block') ;
    $("select[name=city]").fadeIn('slow')

})
```

my browser is ie8 , but not support `"select[name=city] **option**"` command for select,

TanX from all

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because `owner` isn't valid HTML element attribute. Change it to data-owner.

and there's syntax error

```
$("select[name=city].fadeIn('slow')");
```

should be

```
$("select[name=city]").fadeIn('slow')
```